# Regex cleaning some html string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse some html from a website.

The html may contain some invalid html which cause that the parser are not able to parse the html.

this is my regex that I wrote

```js
/(\[class\]((=)("|')?.*("|')))|(\[class\])|((\[id\]((=)("|')?.*("|')))|(\[id\]))/
```

This will remove all [class] and [id] attr

My above regex work fine with some html but not all
example 1 that works

```html
<div class="par fontsize-16" [class]="'par fontsize-' + fontsize"><p>the two of them left that everyone came back to their senses.</p>
```

but it dose not work with

```html
      </div><span id="saved" hidden>Settings saved..</span><div class="clear"></div><div class="par fontsize-16" [class]="'par fontsize-' + fontsize"><p>It wasn't " until the two of them left that everyone came back to their senses.</p>
```

This is caused by the string  `It wasn't "` which is removed.

I only want to remove the attr and its content and not the tags content

is it possible

### Final solution

Thanx to @IT goldman I ended up with a solution.
I am posting it incase someone needs it.

```js
function cleanHTML(html, attrs) {
  try {
    attrs.forEach(attr => {
      var pos = 0
      while ((pos = html.indexOf(attr)) > -1) {
        var sep = null;
        var state = 0;
        for (var i = pos + attr.length; i < html.length; i++) {
          var c = html.charAt(i);
          if (c == '=') {
            state = 1
            continue;
          }
          if (state == 1 && (c.trim() === '"' || c.trim() === "'")) {
            sep = c;
            break;
          } else if (["'", '"', "=", ""].indexOf(c.trim()) === -1)
            break;
        }


        if (sep) {
          const closingPos = html.indexOf(">", pos);
          const pos_q = html.indexOf(sep, pos);
          let pos_q2 = html.indexOf(sep, pos_q + 1);
          if (pos_q2 > closingPos) // none closing attr
            pos_q2 = closingPos - 1;
          html = html.substring(0, pos) + html.substring(pos_q2 + 1)
        } else html = html.substring(0, pos) + html.substring(pos + attr.length + (state == 1 ? 1 : 0));
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return html;
}


var src = `<span [class]= [class][class] id="saved" [id]hidden [class] =  '"kjhsdf->Settings saved..</span><div class="clear"></div><div class="par fontsize-16" [class]="'par fontsize-' + fontsize"><p>It wasn't " until the two of them left that everyone came back to their senses.</p><a [class]='another'>sasportas</a>`
console.log(cleanHTML(src, ["[class]", "[id]"]));
```

Comment: Don’t use regex for parsing html

Comment: I am not using regexp to parse the html I am using something else but it is not able to parse it because the html string is wrong

Comment: So you want to remove all the `[class]="property"` and same for `[id]` ? Could the attribute be inside `'` and not `"` sometimes?

Comment: yes, it is exactly as you say. see the html example above

Comment: You can match your second one by taking the first `.*`, adding a `?` at the end to make it lazy so it stops at the first instance of the following pattern rather than the last, then move it into your `("|')?` right before it along with the `("|')` right after it. This would look like `("?.*?"|'?.*?')`. However, RegEx is not complex enough to properly read (parse) HTML. This will likely not work in all cases, and it's very likely you won't be able to make a regular expression that can work in all cases.

Comment: You can use a backreference to match the quote.  Try `/(\[(id|class)\]=(["'])?.*?\3)/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little function to remove specific attributes (and their values) from an HTML string.

```js
var src = `</div><span [class] [class][class] id="saved" [id]hidden>Settings saved..</span><div class="clear"></div><div class="par fontsize-16" [class]="'par fontsize-' + fontsize"><p>It wasn't " until the two of them left that everyone came back to their senses.</p><a [class]='another'>sasportas</a>`

function clean_str(src, attributes_to_remove) {
  attributes_to_remove.forEach(function(attr) {
    var pos
    while ((pos = src.indexOf(attr)) > -1) {
      var sep;
      var state = 0;
      for (var i = pos + attr.length; i < src.length; i++) {
        var c = src.charAt(i);
        if (c == '=') {
          state = 1
          continue;
        }
        if (state == 0 && c.trim()) {
          sep = null;
          break;
        }
        if (state == 1 && c.trim()) {
          sep = c;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (sep) {
        var pos_q = src.indexOf(sep, pos);
        var pos_q2 = src.indexOf(sep, pos_q + 1);
        src = src.substring(0, pos) + src.substring(pos_q2 + 1)
      } else {
        src = src.substring(0, pos) + src.substring(pos + attr.length)
      }
    }
  })
  return src;
}

console.log(clean_str(src, ["[class]", "[id]"]))
```

Comment: this will not be able to handle [class]=''

Comment: I'll try to fix that

Comment: that looks great, dose changing substr to substring cause a problem ? as substr is decripted

Comment: I'll try to fix that

Comment: I have tested it, it works great but if you add only [class] with out anything, it breaks. eg change to `<span id="saved" [class] hidden>` and you will see the problem

Comment: hmm... ok no problem the basis is there. and you were right about replacing substr with substring

Comment: This works great now thx, I also added `if (src[pos+attr.length] === "=")` above `for` just to make sure there is not any mistake

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick: `/\[(?:class|id)](?:=(["']).*?\1)?/`

```js
const regex = /\[(?:class|id)](?:=(["']).*?\1)?/g
const badHtml = `</div><span id="saved" hidden>Settings saved..</span><div class="clear"></div><div class="par fontsize-16" [class]="'par fontsize-' + fontsize"><p>It wasn't " until the two of them left that everyone came back to their senses.</p>`

document.getElementById('input').innerText = badHtml
document.getElementById('output').innerText = regex[Symbol.replace](badHtml, '')
```

```html
Input
<pre id="input"></pre>
Output
<pre id="output"></pre>
```